# How this web site achieves a fluid/liquid layout

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

In this web site, [www.emblematiq.com](http://www.emblematiq.com/), the layout is fluid/liquid. I was looking at the code but can not seem to figure out how it is achieved. Looks like a fixed width layout with the `canvas` element having a width of 1180px.

Can't seem to find

1. Any media queries in the CSS.
2. Widths are set with px and not %.
3. The JavaScript/jQuery involved does not seem to to be related to it.

I am sure I am missing something obvious but for the life of me can't find the responsible code for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page uses two systems to achieve "fluid liquid layout" :

## Javascript

In `main.js` we can see :

```
$(window).bind("smartresize", function( event ) {
    if($("#contactForm")[0]) {enableContact(); if($(window).width() >= 460){doContact();} else {undoContact();}}
    if($("body").hasClass("home")){setTitleHeight();}
});
```

The smartresize event is brought by the [jQuery smartresize plugin](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize), used to get throttled resize events (to avoid overloading the JS engine).

This function enables and disables UI elements depending on the window width, and adapts the title height using a custom function making heavy use of jQuery.

## CSS `media` selectors

In `main.css` we can see, for example :

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1180px) {body{min-width:944px;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:944px) {body{min-width:708px;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:708px) {body{font-size:13px; min-width:472px;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:472px) {body{font-size:11px; line-height:15px; min-width:236px;}}
```

These rules set different properties according to the element width.

See [w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 2):

The CSS is packed with media queries:  http://www.emblematiq.com/global/main.css

Answer (score 2):

The [main CSS file](http://www.emblematiq.com/global/main.css) is loaded with media queries.

It uses CSS transitions to make the page respond so nicely to layout changes.

Comment: Right. Strange the media queries did'nt show up in the IE developer tools. Oh Well. Fresh/younger eyes see clearer.

Comment: @Jawad - Developer tools will often filter out the things it ignores (you can also see this happening in Firebug with non-Firefox vendor CSS). It's always best to look at the raw code when looking for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

This comes under the blanket phrase "responsive web design" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design. There are various ways of achieving it, as the article explains. Your site may be more adaptable to one of the methods in particular.

Answer (score 0):

According to its source code. I assumed that it's a css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/global/main.css" />
```

Comment: Modernizr only helps determine browser capability.  Respond is a polyfill for media queries.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah! Thats what I thought.